# Dúvida: JS do Google Analitycs executa na função file_get_contents do PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Tenho um site na qual tem o JS do Google Analitycs, acontece que de tempo em tempo eu rodo uma função em file_get_contents no PHP para pegar uma informação nesse site. Minha dúvida é: o Google Analitycs consegue identificar a conexão via file_get_contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, pois isto ocorre do lado do servidor. O que acontece com o processo PHP, o Google Analitycs não conseguirá obter nenhum dado. Após terminar o processo do PHP, é enviado a saída para o browser contendo ou não o HTML. Uma vez que foi enviado e a página renderizada, o Google Analitycs começa a coletar as informações.

Logo, a função file_get_contents não será lida pelo Google Analitycs.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!